# Wird hier bei diesem Nebensatz ein Beistrich benötigt?

Tags: subordinate-clause

Wird hier bei folgendem Nebensatz der zweite Beistrich "(,)" benötigt, oder ist dieser optional?

> Ich finde es interessant, dass viele die sich gegen Deutschkurse äußern(,) selbst Rechtschreibfehler in ihren deutschen Kommentaren machen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dein Satz besteht aus drei Teilen:

1. Der Hauptsatz - "Ich finde es interessant"
2. Ein Objektsatz, der mit der Konjunktion "dass" eingeleitet wird - "dass viele selbst Rechtschreibfehler machen"
3. Ein in den Objektsatz eingeschobener Relativsatz - "die sich gegen Deutschkurse aussprechen"

Alle diese drei Teile müssen voneinander durch Kommata abgetrennt werden, keins davon ist optional (optionale Kommata sind in der deutschen Zeichensetzung übrigens extrem selten, die meisten betreffen Infinitive und wurden erst mit der letzten Rechtschreibreform optional. Im allgemeinen gilt eine Regel zur Kommasetzung verpflichtend):

> Ich finde es interessant, dass viele, die sich gegen Deutschkurse aussprechen, selbst Rechtschreibfehler in ihren Kommentaren machen.

Comment: Danke, jetzt verstehe ich schon etwas mehr davon.
Bist du auch der Meinung, dass "äußern" hier nicht verwendet werden darf/sollte?

Comment: "äußern" ist vollkommen OK. Ich hatte nur vorher wahrscheinlich die andere Antwort gelesen.

Answer (score -1):

Es handelt sich um einen eingeschobenen Relativsatz. Dieser wird natürlich durch Kommas begrenzt.

Außerdem ist das Verb *äußern* falsch, denn man kann sich nicht *gegen etwas äußern*. Es muss **gegen etwas aussprechen** heißen.

> Ich finde es interessant, dass viele **,** die sich gegen Deutschkurse **aussprechen,** selbst Rechtschreibfehler in ihren deutschen Kommentaren machen.

Comment: Wieso kann man sich nicht gegen etwas äußern? Dudens 1. Punkt zu äußern ist aussprechen.

Comment: Die Konstruktion sich gegen etwas äussern ist schon seit dem 19. Jahrhundert dokumentiert:

**Heidelberger Jahrbücher der Literatur** [1823]: "Auch Recens. hat schon mehrmals sich gegen diese gewiss nur nachtheilige Sitte geäussert, und will daher nichts wiederholen". **Schmollers Jahrbuch für Gesetzgebung, Verwaltung und Volkswirtschaft im Deutschen Reiche** [1913]: "Dieser äußerte sich gegen den Antrag Kardorff". etc.

Comment: Wenn man ältlich klingen will, kann man *äußern* so benutzen, sicher. Man kann gewiss auch viel anderes Thun, um eben solches zu erreichen.

Comment: Die "ältliche" Konstruktion ist "sich gegen[über] *einer Person* äussern": [1803] "Ein Adjudant äußerte sich gegen Peschinger: “Der Obergeneral habe eine Strafe von hundert Stock streichen für Agliardis bestimmt""